# Accessing nested values from YAML data in a Twig template

Tags: variables, twig, yaml

I am trying to access nested YML data in a Twig template. My YML data is structured like this:

```
card_default:
  card_title: 'Card Title'
  card_header: 'This is the card header on a multi-part card'
  card_text: "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content."
  card_link: 'https://github.com/phase2/particle'
  card_background: primary
  card_image_location: top
  card_footer: "This is the card footer"
  text_color: uk-dark
  card_body: "This is some card body text"
  card_style: default
card_image:
  card_more_stuff in here....
```

... and then I call some of the data in a Twig template like this:

```
 {% include '@molecules/card/_card.twig' with {
          card_default: {
              card_title: card_title,
              card_text: card_text,
              card_background: 'primary',
              card_link: card_link,
              card_link_text: card_link_text,
              card_link_class: card_link_class,
          }
      } only %}
```

But that does not seem to work. I have a feeling the way I am trying to do this is not quite right but a search didn't give me any more insight. Essentially I want to access the values within `card_default`.

I can see all the data in the array if I dump with `{{ dump(card_default) }}`

```
array(14) { ["card_title"]=> string(10) "Card Title" ["card_header"]=> string(44) "This is the card header on a multi-part card" ["card_text"]=> string(94) "Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content." ["card_link"]=> string(34) "https://github.com/phase2/particle" ["card_link_text"]=> string(9) "Read more" ["card_link_class"]=> string(27) "uk-button uk-button-default" ["card_background"]=> string(7) "primary" ["card_width"]=> int(25) ["card_image_location"]=> string(3) "top" ["card_footer"]=> string(23) "This is the card footer" ["list"]=> array(2) { ["list_flush"]=> bool(true) ["items"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["item_text"]=> string(15) "Cras justo odio" } [1]=> array(1) { ["item_text"]=> string(23) "Dapibus ac facilisis in" } [2]=> array(1) { ["item_text"]=> string(18) "Vestibulum at eros" } } } ["text_color"]=> string(7) "uk-dark" ["card_body"]=> string(27) "This is some card body text" ["card_style"]=> string(7) "default" }
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is in the variable `card_default`, so it should be e.g. `card_default.card_title`
but instead of creating a whole new object you just could do this in 2 ways:

*YAML*

```
foo:
    bar: 'foobar'
    number: 42
```

*main.twig*

```
{% include "full.twig" with { 'foo' : foo } only %}
{% include "slim.twig" with foo only %}
```

*full.twig*

```
{{ foo.bar }}
```

*slim.twig*

```
{{ number }}
```

Comment: Although that would work, it does not keep my base template DRY. I figured this out, all I needed to do was to call it properly, I'll post an answer below.

Comment: Well yeah, that is what I stated in my first sentence actually :)

Answer (score -1):

I figured this out, I just needed to map the nested items properly like so:

```
  {% include '@molecules/card/_card.twig' with {
      card_title: card_default.card_title,
      card_text: card_default.card_text,
      card_background: 'primary',
      card_link: card_default.card_link,
      card_link_text: card_default.card_link_text,
      card_link_class: card_default.card_link_class,
  }  %}
```

In the above code, `card_default` is mapped in the variable portion of the array, i.e., after the colon. `card_link: card_default.card_link,`